# Will I lose trophies when creating a PSN account?

Tags: ps4, psn

So, I wanted to create a PSN account to allow me to get online trophies (I'm a huge trophy-collector), but I've already gotten some trophies, and I'm afraid of losing them and having to do them all over again.

If I create a PSN account, will those offline trophies be sent to my account? Or would I have to do them all over again?

Comment: If it is anything like Xbox, then no. Xbox allows you to simply make a profile Live available. I would assume Playstation does the same.

Answer (score 3):

All you existing trophies will be synced to your new PSN account.

Confirmed in [this thread](https://www.playstationtrophies.org/forum/tech-centre/48187-trophies-without-psn-id.html).

Also, it's possible to manually force trophies synchronization with PSN account - see "Manual trophy sync" [here](https://www.playstation.com/en-au/get-help/help-library/apps---features/playstation-apps---features/about-trophies/).